# What would be the best way to determine which fields within a JSON object in each row contain the most null/empty values?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with an `id` column and a `data` column. The `data` column contains JSON objects with the following keys:

- `age`
- `name`
- `gender`
- `addresses` (array)
- `ratings`
- `specialties` (array)

I want to find the 3 keys within each JSON object that are most often left empty or null.

I know how I'd approach this in Python; I'd just iterate through each row and in turn iterate through each value within the `data` JSON object of that row and store the results in a dictionary. If a null/empty value is detected it would first check to see if that key already exists in the results dictionary, and if so += 1 to the value of that key. If the key doesn't already exist in the results dictionary, it would be added to the dictionary with a starting value of 1. From there I'd just sort the resulting dictionary and take the 3 keys with the 3 highest values.

For the sake of clarity, here's an example scenario:

- Row 1: values of `age` and `addresses` keys in the data JSON object are empty/null
- Row 2: values of `age` and `specialties` keys in the data JSON object are empty/null
- Row 3: values of `ratings` and `addresses` keys in the data JSON object are empty/null
- Row 4: value of `name` key in the data JSON object is empty/null
- Row 5: value of `age` key in the data JSON object is empty/null
- Row 6: values of `age` and `addresses` keys in the data JSON object are empty/null
- Row 7: value of `specialties` key in the data JSON object is empty/null

In this example, the 3 keys that are most often left empty or null would be:

1. `age` (empty/null in 4 rows)
2. `addresses` (empty/null in 3 rows)
3. `specialties` (empty/null in 2 rows)

How would I accomplish this in Postgres? I figure I'll have to make a custom looping function, but I've never done anything like that in Postgres before so I'd really appreciate some guidance here. Any suggestions for the best way to tackle this?

Comment: They do occur only once – per row. Each row in the data column contains a JSON object with the keys I mentioned. I'm trying to determine which of these keys are the most neglected overall (neglected in this instance would refer to the values being empty or null). For example: age and addresses are null in row 1, age and specialties are null in row 2, ratings is null in row 3, age is null in row 4. In this instance the top most neglected key is age.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use loops or a custom iteration. With an SQL mindset, counting things from a table and sorting by the counts is even simpler than in Python.

The secret sauce here is composed of the [`jsonb_each` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and a [`LATERAL` subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
SELECT key, count(*)
FROM example t,
LATERAL jsonb_each(t.data)
WHERE value = 'null'
GROUP BY key
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

<sup>([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=35a4a8158a451a7c01915750979f1e82))</sup>

However, notice that by iterating through `data` (just like in Python) you won't notice if a JSON object doesn't have the property at all - it is only iterated if it exists. A column where `data = '{}'` wouldn't be counted at all. If you wanted to treat those as "empty", you would actually need to try accessing the object with any existing key. This can be done by joining against the known keys:

```
SELECT key, count(*)
FROM example t,
UNNEST(ARRAY['age', 'name', 'gender', 'addresses', 'ratings', 'specialties']) AS keys(key)
WHERE data->key IS NULL OR data->key = 'null'
GROUP BY key
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

<sup>([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dcb105c990d2093fe2668233eeea72ac))</sup>

Comment: BTW `lateral` is not needed here, it required for subqueries: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=196bb9045c1ecca32f11af011ff7d644

Comment: @Abelisto Yes, the linked docs say: "*for functions the key word is optional*" …"*but we use it for clarity.*" :-)